# Creating a subset of words from a corpus in R

Tags: r, corpus, word-cloud

I have a 1,500-row vector created from a Twitter search using the XML package.  I have then converted it to a Corpus to be used with the tm package.  I want to ultimately create a wordcloud with some (the most frequent) of those words, so I converted it to a TermDocumentMatrix to be able to find terms with a minimum frequency.  I create the object "a", which is a list of those terms.

```
a <- findFreqTerms(mydata.dtm, 10)
```

The wordcloud package does not work on document matrices.  So now, I want to filter the original vector to include only the words included in the "a" object (If I use the object itself, of course, I only have one instance of each of the frequent words).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, welcome to SP.  Can you please paste in a sample of your data.   You can use `dput(myData)`  If it is too large you can use `dput(head(myData, 10))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15506118/1036500

Answer (score 6):

You can convert your tdm object into a matrix and work with that to get something that `wordcloud` can work with:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
# example data from the tm package
data(crude)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude,
                      control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                     stopwords = TRUE))
v <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm))
names(v) <- rownames(as.matrix(tdm))
v <- sort(v, decreasing=T)
```

Now with this you can filter out infrequent words with standard subsetting (`[`), or you can use the `min.freq` argument to `wordcloud` when you want to plot:

```
wordcloud(names(v), v, min.freq=10, scale=c(10,.3))
```

[image: wordcloud]