# How to create a word cloud from a corpus in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, gensim, word-cloud

From [Creating a subset of words from a corpus in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502802/creating-a-subset-of-words-from-a-corpus-in-r), the answerer can easily convert a `term-document matrix` into a word cloud easily.

Is there a similar function from python libraries that takes either a raw word textfile or `NLTK` corpus or `Gensim` Mmcorpus into a word cloud?

The result will look somewhat like this:
[image]

Comment: After some mad reimplementation, here's the shameless plug but here's a not so `sklearn` solution that uses Andreas Mueller's code. https://github.com/alvations/translation-cloud

Answer (score 19):

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 # chosen at random by flipping a coin; it was heads
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()

show_wordcloud(Samsung_Reviews_Negative['Reviews'])
show_wordcloud(Samsung_Reviews_positive['Reviews'])
```

[image]

Comment: I am doing something similar to what you have posted. Where can I get the full code?

Answer (score 12):

**Example of amueller's code in action**

In command-line / terminal:

```
sudo pip install wordcloud
```

Then run python script:

```
## Simple WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS 

text = 'all your base are belong to us all of your base base base'

def generate_wordcloud(text): # optionally add: stopwords=STOPWORDS and change the arg below
    wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf',
                          width=800, height=400,
                          relative_scaling = 1.0,
                          stopwords = {'to', 'of'} # set or space-separated string
                          ).generate(text)
    
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 4))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis("off")
    ## Pick One:
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig("WordCloud.png")

generate_wordcloud(text)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually this is a pretty deceptive word cloud. Given that it's normalized based on the pixels and the length of the word although the counts are the same, that's why US is bigger than base.

Comment: See documentation. The plot can be altered for stopwords and relative_scaling (frequency vs. rank when scaling words). By default relative_scaling is 0 (Rank), I believe you are looking for relative_scaling = 1.0 (Frequency).

Comment: Could you put that into the answer? And also generate the different word cloud with 1.0? Thanks! That'll help future readers =)

Comment: I will like to add a minor correction to the stopwords parameter as `stopwords = {'to', 'of'}`

Comment: How to save the image in high resolution?

Comment: Read lines 164-168 of amueller's code. Source: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/wordcloud.py You'll need to add arguments for the width and height of the canvas, and add a line for the size of the figure size if you intend to save.

Answer (score 10):

In case you require these word clouds for showing them in website or web app you can convert your data to json or csv format and load it to a JavaScript visualisation library such as [d3](http://d3js.org/). [Word Clouds on d3](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/)

If not, Marcin's answer is a good way for doing what you describe.

Answer (score 3):

here is the short code

```
#make wordcoud

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 # chosen at random by flipping a coin; it was heads
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    show_wordcloud(text_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
cvData = cv.fit_transform(DF["W"]).toarray()
cvDF = pd.DataFrame(data=cvData,          columns=cv.get_feature_names())
cvDF["target"] = DF["T"]

def w_count(tar):
    MO = cvDF[cvDF["target"] == tar].drop("target",axis=1)
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for i in range(MO.shape[0]):
        for j in cvDF.drop("target",axis=1):
             if MO.iloc[i][j]>4:
                x.append(j)
                y.append(MO.iloc[i][j])
    return x,y

for i in cvDF["target"]:
    x,y = w_count(i)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.title(i)
    plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
    plt.bar(x,y)
    plt.show()

for c in range(len(DF)):
    w=[]
    for i,j in zip(cvDF.T[c].index, cvDF.T[c].values):
        a=[]
        if j > 1:
            a.append(i)
            a.append(j)
            w.append(a)
    pd.DataFrame(w)
    data = dict(w)
    wc = WordCloud(width=800, height=400, max_words=200).generate_from_frequencies(data)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title(DF['T'][c])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: pr = agc.fit_predict(features.toarray())
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(pca_feat[:,0], pca_feat[:,1], c = brc_pred)