# Wordcloud in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, word-cloud, pytagcloud

I am trying to create Wordclouds in Python running on Windows. I have tried the below packages but they do not seem to work for me:

- Wordcloud by A Mueller - the installer for windows seems broken and I cannot install it. Seems to be working fine on Linux and Mac OS. My requirement is specifically for Windows.
- I referred this post [How to create a word cloud from a corpus in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645799/how-to-create-a-word-cloud-from-a-corpus-in-python) but the same problem persists because they are all using the Wordcloud package and it does not seem to install on Windows.
- pywordcloud - Dont know how to work it. Cant seem to find any documentation around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
- pytagcloud - Seems to hang up for a large corpus of text. However, my feeling is that I am not using it correctly. Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

I would appreciate greatly if someone could point me in the right direction please.

Comment: share the code you wrote or explain in detail how you went about installing the wordcloud package.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the wordcloud library by A Mueller. Download the folder from https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud and then install the Wordcloud using

> python setup.py build_ext -i

and then run

> python setup.py install

More info you can get here https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/125